# Oracle Enforce Uniqueness

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, unique-constraint, unique-index

I need to enforce uniqueness on specific data in a table (~10 million rows). This example data illustrates the rule -
For code=X the part# cannot be duplicate. For any other code there can be duplicate part#. e.g ID 8 row can't be there but ID 6 row is fine. There are several different codes in the table and part# but uniqueness is desired only for one code=X.

```
ID      CODE        PART#
1       A           R0P98
2       X           R9P01
3       A           R0P98
4       A           R0P44
5       X           R0P44
6       A           R0P98
7       X           T0P66
8       X           T0P66
```

The only way I see is to create a trigger on the table and check for PART# for code=X before insert or update. However, I fear this solution may slow down inserts and updates on this table.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle, you can create a unique index on an expression for this:

```
create unique index myidx
    on mytable (case when code = 'X' then part# end);
```

Comment: This is one of the cases I think the SQL Standard is deficient. SQL constraints cannot enforce this rule. It's just weird to use an index to to the job of a constraint.

Comment: @TheImpaler: I find that a unique index is a correct tool for this job. Oracle, however, is quite limited in that regard. Postgres, for example, as proper partial unique index, like: `create unique index myidx on mytable(part#) where (code = 'X')`

Comment: @GMB - thank you! I have an additional problem implementing index this way. The value of code is not fix on different boxes. There is a code master table that stores codes for that box/schema. So if I try like below - it doesn't work.  Of course I can dynamically create it getting that code value for each box/schema but there is a possibility someone may update code for that box/schema. However master code will never change.  create unique index myidx
    on mytable (case when code = (select code from master_codes where master_code = 'PRAM') then part# end);

Comment: How can add another column, say ID, to this index?

Comment: @blueolive: that would be something like `(case when code = 'X' then part# || '&&' || id end);` (assuming that `&&` is a sequence of characters that never appears in your strings)